# Facing Error While Updating Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I have tried two different update SQL query but facing the error:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

And

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I don`t know where I am doing wrong?

Please find the two queries below.

Query One:

```
update DB1..UScustomer 
set area='India' 
WHERE (customerid = '1') AND (area = 'US') 
  AND (areatransid in (select areaTransactionId 
                       from DB2..AllCustomer 
                       where area='US' and customerid='1' and statusId='2'))
```

Query Two:

```
update DB1..UScustomer 
SET area='India' 
from DB1..UScustomer M1 
inner join DB2..AllCustomer M2 
      on M1.areatransid=S1.areaTransactionId and S1.statusId=2 
WHERE (customerid = '1') AND (area = 'US')
```

Comment: you could try searching the errors on the site before posting as the answers are probably out there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D++Null+value+is+eliminated+by+an+aggregate+or+other+SET+operation.

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+Subquery+returned+more+than+1+value.+This+is+not+permitted+when+the+subquery+follows+%3D%2C+%21%3D%2C+%3C%2C+%3C%3D+%2C+%3E%2C+%3E%3D+or+when+the+subquery+is+used+as+an+expression.+The+statement+has+been+terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query two like this.
**Query Two :**

```
update M1 
    SET area='India' 
    from DB1..UScustomer M1 
    inner join DB2..AllCustomer M2 
          on M1.areatransid=M2.areaTransactionId and M2.statusId=2 
    WHERE (M1.customerid = '1') AND (M1.area = 'US') AND (M2.customerid = '1') AND (M2.area = 'US')
```